# Trying to resize text on click with Javascript, what am I doing wrong?

Tags: javascript, html, events, onclick, resize

I'm trying and failing to create an on click function to resize some text. Can anyone see what I'm doing wrong? I definitely know the code isn't correct, because I'm such a noob at Javascript.
Cheers in advance!

```
    <div class="Appraisals" id="change">
  <div align="left"><span class="Block1">Random text that nobody cares about.
Random text that nobody cares about.Random text that nobody cares about. </span></div> 
    <button type="button" 
onclick="document.getElementById('change').style.height "50px"; >
Click Me!</button>
</div>
<div class="inspire"> <img src="inspire.jpg" alt="Crest" height="200"></div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it should be

```
document.getElementById('change').style.fontSize = '50px'
```

instead of:

```
document.getElementById('change').style.height "50px";
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/0ztwhhb2/6/)

Comment: Cheers for the reply, I tried that and as before, nothing.

Comment: Yeah. Even using Fiddle that u recommended did nothing, any further tips?

Comment: No just, nothing is happening. The button appears, I click it and nothing. just me sitting in my underpants staring worryingly at the clock on my desktop! too much info? haha

Comment: haha i also overlooked the part that says text size, looks like you got the answer

Comment: @user3071724 haha ok try the new fiddle I added and tell me if thats what you want to do

Comment: Man, from this day on, you will be known as my saviour. I have spent about an hour trying this, because I arrogantly overlooked a guideline. Thank you forever!

Comment: @user3071724 haha no problem. Glad to help. Can you check this off as resolved then?

Answer (score 0):

Option one:

Call myFunction onclick and pass the ID and the font-size, them handle with the manipulation in the script file. (good)

HTML:

```
    <div class="Appraisals" id="change">
      <div align="left"><span class="Block1">Random text that nobody cares about.
         Random text that nobody cares about.Random text that nobody cares about.</span>
      </div> 
      <button type="button" onclick="myFunction('change', '50px');" > Click Me!</button>
       Click Me!
      </button>
    </div>
    <div class="inspire"> <img src="inspire.jpg" alt="Crest" height="200"></div>
```

JS:

```
<script>
   function myFunction(element, clr) {
     var changeId = document.getElementById(element);
     changeId.style.fontSize=clr;
   }
</script>
```

Option two:

handle with the manipulation in the HTML. (not good)

```
    <div class="Appraisals" id="change">
      <div align="left"><span class="Block1">Random text that nobody cares about.
         Random text that nobody cares about.Random text that nobody cares about.</span>
      </div> 
      <button type="button" onclick="document.getElementById("change").style.fontSize="50px"" > Click Me!</button>
       Click Me!
      </button>
    </div>
    <div class="inspire"> <img src="inspire.jpg" alt="Crest" height="200"></div>
```

Option three:

Use jquery. (very good)

First call jquery cdn:

```
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Them:

```
<script>
  $(document).ready(function() {
     $('button').click(function() {
       $('#change').css('font-size', '50px');
     });
  });
</script>
```

Comment: Sorry, I might sound like an idiot here, but is "myFunction" where I put my div id or... As I said, I'm pathetically new at this!

Comment: No it has to be javascript, otherwise I'm going to look like a blatent cheat. I just can't find anything on how to change the text size in javascript.

Comment: just a sec.. i will change my answer

Comment: Cheers. I am half asleep and have little capacity to learn at this time! :)

Comment: is "myFunction" where I put my div id?

Comment: nop.. you need put myFunction in the button tag, cause you want tricker the function when you click the button..

Comment: @user3071724 you should use a external js file to handle with the manipulation.. use onclick is not a good in this days..

Answer (score 0):

Do you want to change the size of the text.. not the height?

```
document.getElementById('change').style = 'font-size:50px;'
```

Comment: Yeah! That's exactly it!